# Why is Component not working for Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: pi-2, output, composite-video

**Note:** It may not be working because of which cable I am using.

So I have a **Raspberry Pi 2 Model B** and I want to connect it to a computer monitor that only takes composite video input.

This is what I'm using to output composite video:

[image]

I've edited the config.txt file to ignore HDMI output and use NTSC video.  I've also commented force_hdmi so that it wouldn't force that output.

But this is all I get:

[image]

No input signal.

What should I do?

Ps I'm running on the **Raspbian** operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching the red and the yellow.

Comment: Explain further.  Red is audio, how would this work.

Comment: They are somehow switched.

Comment: @ZacharyVincze Red is only audio if the red lead is connected to the audio tip in the socket.  There is no standard.  I had to swap two leads to get composite video to work on my Pi2.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have to press key 2, 3 or 4 to change to compose video, also add this line on config.txt :

> sdtv_mode=2

Also

> hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1

However it may be the wrong cable as explained on raspberry.org

[Raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=81736&start=75#p577977)

Comment: I think it may be the cable as I've already put sdtv_mode=0 (NTSC video) and hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1.

Answer (score 0):

The red plug contained my video (on my cable) also. Your mileage may vary. Do like I did & switch them around until it either works or doesn't.

Comment: This is, more or less, the same as [alb3rtano0012's answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36205/why-is-component-not-working-for-raspberry-pi-2#answer-36217)

Comment: Being it wider it's actually better