# TV screen is black when using analog TV via yellow video cable (with or without scart adapter)

Tags: video, noobs, composite-video

My Pi (1 version B, running OpenELEC and Raspian installed via NOOBS) works like a charm via HDMI (mind you, I also happen to use an HDMI to DVI adapter and I have no problems with that). But I cannot get any kind of video signal when using the yellow video cable.
I set the tv to A/V, get a black screen, power up the Pi, the screen stays black. Does not even blink.

I tried to connect the yellow cable to the yellow adapter on my tv (works to display pictures from my Canon camera) and I have a black screen.
I tried to connect the yellow cable to a scart adapter and with that to the scart input of my TV and still get a black screen. 
I tried this on two tvs - always black.

I also tried to change PAL and NTSC on the newer TV: still black.

Pressing "3" at boot won't help.

(All of this from a freshly powered up RasPi without HDMI cable).
Right now I have hooked up the hdmi output to my Samsung monitor - I can get picture and video, and the analog output to my TV (yellow to yellow). TV is black.

In Openelec I have changed video resolution from 1280x1024 of the Samsung monitor to "desktop", thinking that maybe the tv was trying to eat more than it could chew, but... I do not get the boot screen either. Shouldn't I be at least seeing that?

I want to stress that I get absolutely nothing on screen. It's not black and white video. It's utter darkness.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: I haven't done it but you need to force the pi to use the composite output instead of HDMI.  I thought there was a better answer to link but start here http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/36208/19485

Comment: Thanks, pressing buttons at boot apparently did nothing for me (I'll try again in a more systematic way). But editing the config.txt file in Raspian by adding sdtv_mode=2 and hdmi_ignore_hotplug=1 did the trick, at least in Raspian. I'll have to figure out how to do that for OpenELEC but at least now I know all my hardware is in working order. I will edit my question when I have found a clean-cut way to switch between modes.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up to Tyson's very helpful comment and for future reference, here's what the problem was.

From this page: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=87619, an answer from user rpdom states:

> If you used NOOBS and setup up on your [HDMI device] then the Pi has been forced
> to HDMI output and will not switch to RCA.
>
> What you need to do is boot up on your [HDMI device], then using a terminal and
>
> `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`
>
> comment out the line that says
>
> `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`
>
> by putting a # in front of the line to make
>
> `#hdmi_force_hotplug=1`.
>
> Then your Pi should detect if an HDMI screen is connected and use RCA
> if it isn't.

(I edited "TV" into "HDMI device" to avoid confusion).
The force directive above is forcing output on HDMI even if there is no HDMI cable detected.